# merge json file with csv file to pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a json file like

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "NBG_DATA.CBSWBI",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ 5.9790846852, 51.8962916127 ],
                        [ 5.9787704282, 51.8970121894 ],
                        [ 5.9115581116, 51.9006415588 ], 
                        [ 5.9115375181, 51.9007482452 ], 
                        [ 5.911477843, 51.9011278526 ] 
                    ] 
                ] 
        }, 
    "properties" : { 
        "WK_CODE" : "WK170500", "WK_NAAM" : "Bemmel", "POPULATION" : "35000"
    }
}
```

with the field WK_CODE.

this json file i want to merge with a pandas df  with the same WK_CODE

I want to merge the json and csv/df together so i can have count population per WK_CODE in the json file and then to a dataframe
how can i do that?

Comment: Can you show a better example with a full json file containing the WK_CODE? It is hard to understand where it is expected to appear in the file.

Comment: i want to merge the json and csv/df together so i can have count population per WK_CODE in the json file and then  to a dataframe },
   "properties" : {
    "WK_CODE" : "WK170500",
    "WK_NAAM" : "Bemmel", "POPULATION" : "35000"
   }

Comment: There are now information about your question at 3 different places (question itself, comments and an "answer"). In the title you mention csv, there is nothing at all about csv here. It is not clear what you want to do. Please take all that information and edit everything into your question with a clear input, your goal and a desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a smal part of the json file

```
{
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ 5.911477843, 51.9011278526 ],
                        [ 5.9114210585, 51.9014890654 ],
                        [ 5.9115581116, 51.9006415588 ],
                        [ 5.9115375181, 51.9007482452 ],
                        [ 5.911477843, 51.9011278526 ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "WK_CODE" : "WK170500"
                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load your json from a file:

```
import json
with open('path/to/file.json') as fh:
    json_data = json.load(fh)
```

For our sake, let's say you loaded the data and it looks like this:

```
json_data =  { 
    "type" : "Feature", 
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" : [ [ [ 5.911477843, 51.9011278526 ], [ 5.9114210585, 51.9014890654 ], [ 5.9115581116, 51.9006415588 ], [ 5.9115375181, 51.9007482452 ], [ 5.911477843, 51.9011278526 ] ] ] }, 
    "properties" : { 
        "WK_CODE" : "WK170500", "WK_NAAM" : "Bemmel", "POPULATION" : "35000"
    }
}
```

Let's create a main df and also a df_json based on this json_data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'WK_CODE': ['WK170500', 'WK170501'], 'field2': [1,2]})
    WK_CODE WK_NAAM POPULATION
0   WK170500    Bemmel  35000

>>>df_json = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data["properties"], orient="index").T
    WK_CODE field2
0   WK170500    1
1   WK170501    2
```

Next use pd.merge:

```
>>> pd.merge(df, df_json, on='WK_CODE', how='left')
    WK_CODE field2  WK_NAAM POPULATION
0   WK170500    1   Bemmel  35000
1   WK170501    2   NaN NaN
```